# How to parse the value from webpage to python?

Tags: python, json

I want to extract the value from the given xpath:

```
'//*[@id="octable"]/tbody/tr[34]/td[8]/b
```

to Python.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

pageContent=requests.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=209&symbol=INFY&symbol=INFY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17')

tree = html.fromstring(pageContent.content)

g=tree.xpath('//*[@id="octable"]/tbody/tr[34]/td[8]/b/text()')

print(g)
```

Expected result: `7,962,000`

Actual result: `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Using `g=tree.xpath('//*[@id="octable"]/tr/td[8]/b/text()')` instead of 
`g=tree.xpath('//*[@id="octable"]/tbody/tr[34]/td[8]/b/text()')` produces the expected results.